# Access Custom UINavigationController properties and methods in a UIViewController

Tags: swift, uikit

I made a `UINavigationController` subclass, `MyNavigationController`. I used this navigation controller in the app, which presents different view controllers. I added few properties and custom views to `MyNavigationController`. I want to access those properties from within the view controllers' `navigationController` property but the type of this property is UINavigationController and not `MyNavigationController` (I understand why) and `navigationController` property cannot be overridden (So making my own `UIViewController` class won't help, and I want to preserve `UINavigationController` default animations etc).

How can I change UIViewController's navigationController property type and make all `MyNavigationController` properties, methods and views accessible? 
Couldn't figure this out...

Any ideas? Thanks! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast it to your custom class type

```
if let navController = self.navigationController as? MyNavigationController {
        navController.customMethod()
    }
```

Comment: Shame on me for not figuring this out haha, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

`(self.navigationController as? MyNavigationController).customMethod()`